# Center of quadrangular

Tags: algorithm, vector, geometry

Having 4 points **A** `(ax, ay)`, **B** `(bx, by)`, **C** `(cx, cy)` and **D** `(dx, dy)` that describe any quadrangular in 2D, with `x` and `y` in range `[-100, 100]` I would like to calculate point **E** `(ex, ey)`, which would be a center of this quadrangular.

What algorithm can be used for such calculation and why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The formula for a [polygon's centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon) is easily expressed in *Mathematica*:

```
PolygonCentroid[pts_?MatrixQ] := With[{dif = Map[Det, Partition[pts, 2, 1, {1, 1}]]},
                       ListConvolve[{{1, 1}}, Transpose[pts], {-1, -1}].dif/(3 Total[dif])]
```

This works for any `Polygon[]`, not just quadrilaterals.

Comment: I'll note that I used this routine previously to help with [coloring the proposed mathematica.SE logo](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/395)...

Comment: Thank you for prompt answer. Where can I find a algorithm/formula in simple math that can be used for coding in programming language such as C, Perl, etc.?

Comment: @Ωmega: I linked to the formula already; you should not have any trouble translating the formula to your computing environment of choice. If you do have trouble, then this site is not the place to ask questions not related to *Mathematica*.

Comment: I have notice the link now. Thanks.

Comment: @J.M. I wonder if the OP wants the centroid, or another `center` definition ...

Comment: @bel: good point. At least, all those possibilities coalesce in the square case...

Comment: @J.M. Ahhh! The infamous pointlike massless cow ...

Comment: @belisarius I immediately thought of spherical horses in vacuum when I read J.M.'s comment.

Comment: In the convex case you can just average the vertex coordinates. I think that gives the usual centroid. Well, it gives something plausible.