# How can we make publication-quality PlotMarkers without version 10?

Tags: plotting, graphics, polygons, marker

Suppose that for [certain reasons](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54593/mathematica-10-formatting-notebook-contents) we are not yet using *Mathematica* version 10, or we have a version with [buggy `PlotMarkers`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54536/what-is-wrong-with-triangle-plotmarkers-in-v-10-0-0/). It is well known that the default markers are font glyphs, and as a result they are difficult to size consistently, as well as [exhibiting inconsistent alignment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/point-renderings-slightly-off-in-mathematica/). Because of this, they are impossible to use in figures intended for publication.

Unfortunately, it is a real nuisance to code markers using graphics primitives, because if we want to use anything apart from the built-in `Disk` and `Rectangle`, the size and alignment points have to be tediously [worked out case-by-case](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56155/change-the-inner-color-of-markers#comment161587_56162) in order to get nice-looking results. And the useful functions [`RegionCentroid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionCentroid.html) and [`RegionMeasure`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html) are new in 10, so they cannot help either.

The `Polygon` graphics primitive seems like an ideal starting point, because we can change its `FaceForm` and `EdgeForm` to produce filled or open markers in a wide variety of different styles. But can anything be done so that we do not have to waste our time working out the vertex coordinates for arbitrary polygons, and then calculating their areas and centroids, whenever we just want to make a publication-quality figure?

Since tastes vary, any and all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The question is about how to get nice results in v9 or earlier.  But what problems does v10 really fix?  Plot markers are still font glyphs, they are still not properly centred, they are still not properly sized with the `Automatic` setting (the squares look much smaller than the disks).  So what does v10 fix?  *Edit:* Ah, I see, we have to change the PlotTheme, right?  But it only seems to have open markers.

Comment: @Szabolcs I am not sure, to be honest. As you might have guessed, I am not using version 10 very much yet, partly due to its incredibly tedious "Formatting notebook contents" messages with non-default color profiles, and partly because I am still on Windows 2003 at home. So I wrote this question with the knowledge that *something* had been improved in version 10, but not really *exactly what* or *how much*. If you think the question can be improved, please feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Based on Oleksandr's excellent [design idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84858/280) here is my re-implementation of his package which offers a much richer set of shapes.

---

### UPDATE from July 2022

A minor update: now the form `PolygonMarker[shape, spec, positions]`, where `spec` contains numeric specification for `size`, returns a list of `Polygon` graphics primitives with centroids placed at `positions` (instead of a `Translate` object, as it was earlier). This change makes straightforward producing explicit primitives intended for the `Region`-based functionality. As always, this version has no incompatible changes.

Added fouth example under the "Scope" section on the [Documentation page for `PolygonMarker`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PolygonMarker), which uses the `Region`-based functionality for producing a high-quality vector figure. This example is also published in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270194/280) post.

The [GitHib version](https://github.com/AlexeyPopkov/PolygonPlotMarkers), the [WFR version](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PolygonMarker) and this post are updated. The package code has now been removed from this post due to exceeding the 30,000 character limit per post.

---

### UPDATE from February 2022

New version is [published](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PolygonMarker) in the WFR! This version introduces new  `PolygonMarker[shape, {size, angle}]` syntax form, which allows to specify the rotation `angle` for the `shape`. Added new built-in shapes: `"DancingStar"`, `"DancingStarRight"`, `"DancingStarThick"`, `"DancingStarThickRight"`, `"FivePointedStarSlim"`, `"SixfoldPinwheel"`, `"SixfoldPinwheelRight"`, `"SevenfoldPinwheel"`, `"SevenfoldPinwheelRight"`. As always, this version has no incompatible changes.

---

### UPDATE from July 2021

New version came out! Now it allows direct generation of `Graphics` objects that can be immediately used as markers for `PlotMarkers`. The new version contains no incompatible changes.

The [Wolfram Function Repository version](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PolygonMarker) is also updated, but now it differs from the version published here and [on GitHub](https://github.com/AlexeyPopkov/PolygonPlotMarkers) in the sense that it does not include the general-purpose functions used to generate the built-in shapes on the fly at the package loading time. It was a decision made by the reviewer to define them simply as lists of points, probably for better performance. The functionality and syntax are the same.

---

### UPDATE from October 2019

Now my function is [published](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PolygonMarker) in the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/) what means that it is available for users of *Mathematica* version 12.0 or higher as `ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"]`. Users of previous versions should install the package as described below (the functionality is the same).

---

### How to install the package

The most recent version of the package can be installed from GitHub by evaluating the following:

```
(* Load the package code *)
package = 
  Import["http://raw.github.com/AlexeyPopkov/PolygonPlotMarkers/master/PolygonPlotMarkers.m", "Text"];

(* Install the package (existing file will be overwritten!) *)
Export[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", 
    "PolygonPlotMarkers.m"}], package, "Text"];
```

For manual installation copy the [code from GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlexeyPopkov/PolygonPlotMarkers/master/PolygonPlotMarkers.m), and save it as "PolygonPlotMarkers.m" in the directory `SystemOpen[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]]`.

---

### Description of the package

> - The basic usage syntax is `PolygonMarker[shape, spec]` where `shape` is a name of built-in shape or a list of 2D coordinates describing a non-selfintersecting polygon, and `spec` can be either `size` or `{size, angle}`.
> - The `size` can be given as a number or in `Scaled` or `Offset` form.
> - The `angle` in radians determines the angle of counterclocwise rotation of shape about its centroid.
> - `PolygonMarker[All]` and `PolygonMarker[]` return the list of names of built-in shapes.
> - `PolygonMarker[shape, spec]` returns `Polygon` graphics primitive which can be used in `Graphics`.
> - `PolygonMarker[shape, size, style]`, where `style` is a list of graphics directives applied to `shape`, returns a `Graphics` object which can be used as a marker for `PlotMarkers`.
> - `PolygonMarker[shape, size, style, options]` returns a `Graphics` object with `options` applied.
> - With `Offset` `size` specification the plot marker has fixed size specified in *printer's points* independent of the size of the plot.
> - `PolygonMarker`s with identical `size` specifications have equal areas (not counting the area taken by the edge of generated `Polygon`). `PolygonMarker[shape, size]` returns shape with area `size2` in the internal coordinate system of `Graphics`. `PolygonMarker[shape, Offset[size]]` returns shape with area `size2` *square printer's points*.
> - The centroid of polygon returned by `PolygonMarker[shape, size]` is always placed at `{0, 0}` in the internal coordinate system of `Graphics`.
> - `PolygonMarker[shape, spec, positions]` where `positions` is a list of 2D coordinates evaluates and `spec` contains numeric specification for `size`, returns a list of `Polygon` graphics primitives with centroids placed at `positions`.
> - `PolygonMarker[shape, spec, positions]` where `positions` is a list of 2D coordinates and `spec` contains `Scaled` or `Offset` specification for `size`, evaluates to `Translate[PolygonMarker[shape, size], positions]`. It represents a collection of multiple identical copies of the shape with centroids placed at `positions`.

---

### Basic examples of use

The complete list of built-in named shapes:

```
Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]

allShapes = PolygonMarker[All]
Tooltip[PolygonMarker[#, 1,
    {FaceForm[Hue@Random[]], EdgeForm[{Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.5], JoinForm["Miter"]}]}, 
    {ImageSize -> 30, PlotRange -> 1.5, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0}], #] & /@ allShapes
```

> ```
> {"TripleCross", "Y", "UpTriangle", "UpTriangleTruncated", 
> "DownTriangle", "DownTriangleTruncated", "LeftTriangle", 
> "LeftTriangleTruncated", "RightTriangle", "RightTriangleTruncated", 
> "ThreePointedStar", "Cross", "DiagonalCross", "Diamond", "Square", 
> "FourPointedStar", "DiagonalFourPointedStar", "FivefoldCross", 
> "Pentagon", "FivePointedStar", "FivePointedStarSlim", 
> "FivePointedStarThick", "DancingStar", "DancingStarRight", 
> "DancingStarThick", "DancingStarThickRight", "SixfoldCross", 
> "Hexagon", "SixPointedStar", "SixPointedStarSlim", "SixfoldPinwheel", 
> "SixfoldPinwheelRight", "SevenfoldCross", "SevenPointedStar",
> "SevenPointedStarNeat", "SevenPointedStarSlim", "SevenfoldPinwheel", 
> "SevenfoldPinwheelRight", "EightfoldCross", "Disk", "H", "I", "N", 
> "Z", "S", "Sw", "Sl"}
> ```

[image: all available shapes]

Automatic plot legends (*Mathematica* 10 or higher) often require a larger value for the `LegendMarkerSize` option in order to avoid cropping. Filled markers which pick up `PlotStyle` and `PlotTheme` automatically:

```
fm[name_String, size_ : 8] := PolygonMarker[name, Offset[size], EdgeForm[]];

SeedRandom[25];
ListPlot[Table[Accumulate@RandomReal[1, 10] + i, {i, 6}], 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  fm /@ {"Triangle", "Y", "Diamond", "ThreePointedStar", "FivePointedStar", "TripleCross"}, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[54, "ColorList"], Joined -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  PointLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 37}, 
   LegendLayout -> (Column[Row /@ #, Spacings -> -1] &)], 
 ImageSize -> 450]
```

> [image: output]

Empty markers which pick up `PlotStyle` and `PlotTheme` automatically:

```
em[name_String, size_ : 7] := PolygonMarker[name, Offset[size],
   {Dynamic@EdgeForm@Directive[CurrentValue["Color"], JoinForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[2], Opacity[1]], FaceForm[White]}, ImagePadding -> 6];

SeedRandom[2];
ListPlot[Table[Accumulate@RandomReal[1, 10] + i, {i, 3}], 
 PlotMarkers -> em /@ {"Triangle", "Square", "Diamond"}, 
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 25}], ImageSize -> 450]

SeedRandom[3];
ListPlot[Table[Accumulate@RandomReal[1, 10] + i, {i, 3}], 
 PlotMarkers -> em /@ {"Triangle", "Square", "Diamond"}, 
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 25}], 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing", ImageSize -> 450]
```

> [image: output]

> [image: output]

Filled markers with lighter filling colors:

```
fm2[name_String, size_ : 9] := PolygonMarker[name, Offset@size, {
    Dynamic@EdgeForm[{CurrentValue["Color"], Opacity[1]}],
    Dynamic@FaceForm@Lighter[CurrentValue["Color"], 0.75]}];

data = Table[{x, BesselJ[k, x]}, {k, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];

ListPlot[data, 
 PlotMarkers -> fm2 /@ {"UpTriangle", "Square", "Circle"}, 
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 450, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.05], Scaled[.1]}]
```

> [image: output]

### Advanced usage

The third argument of `PolygonMarker` can be used to specify the coordinate(s) where the shape should be placed:

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[],EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[1],JoinForm["Miter"]}],
       EdgeForm[Blue],PolygonMarker["Circle",Offset[7],RandomReal[{-1,1},{20,2}]],
       EdgeForm[Red],PolygonMarker["ThreePointedStar",Offset[7],RandomReal[{-1,1},{20,2}]],
       EdgeForm[Darker@Green],PolygonMarker["FourPointedStar",Offset[7],RandomReal[{-1,1},{20,2}]],
       EdgeForm[Darker@Yellow],PolygonMarker["FivePointedStar",Offset[7],RandomReal[{-1,1},{20,2}]]},
      AspectRatio->1/2,ImageSize->450,Frame->True]
```

> [image: output]

Construct a list plot directly from graphics primitives:

```
data = Table[{x, BesselJ[k, x]}, {k, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];
markers = {"Circle", "ThreePointedStar", "FourPointedStar", "FivePointedStar"};
colors = {Blue, Red, Darker@Green, Darker@Yellow};
Graphics[Table[{colors[[i]], Line[data[[i]]], FaceForm[White], 
   EdgeForm[{colors[[i]], AbsoluteThickness[1], JoinForm["Miter"]}], 
   PolygonMarker[markers[[i]], Offset[7], data[[i]]]}, {i, 
   Length[data]}], AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 450, 
 Frame -> True]
```

> [image: output]

Construct a custom list plot where open plot markers have transparent faces for each other (but not for the lines):

```
data = Table[{x, BesselJ[k, x]}, {k, 0, 4}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];
markers = {"Circle", "ThreePointedStar", "FourPointedStar", "DiagonalFourPointedStar", "FivePointedStar"};
colors = {Blue, Red, Green, Yellow, Orange};
background = Darker@Gray;
Graphics[{Table[{colors[[i]], AbsoluteThickness[1.5], Line[data[[i]]], FaceForm[background], EdgeForm[None], 
    PolygonMarker[markers[[i]], Offset[7], data[[i]]]}, {i, Length[data]}], 
  Table[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[{colors[[i]], AbsoluteThickness[1.5], JoinForm["Miter"]}], 
    PolygonMarker[markers[[i]], Offset[7], data[[i]]]}, {i, Length[data]}]}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 500, 
 Frame -> True, Background -> background, FrameStyle -> White, 
 ImagePadding -> {{30, 20}, {25, 20}}]
```

> [image: output]

### Neat Examples

Center markers which pick up `PlotStyle` and `PlotTheme` automatically:

```
cfm[name_String, size_ : 9] := Show[
   PolygonMarker[name, Offset@size, {FaceForm[White],
     Dynamic@EdgeForm[{CurrentValue["Color"], AbsoluteThickness[1], Opacity[1]}]}],
   PolygonMarker[name, Offset[size/2], EdgeForm[None]]];

data = Table[{x, BesselJ[k, x]}, {k, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];

ListPlot[data, 
 PlotMarkers -> cfm /@ {"UpTriangle", "Square", "Circle"}, 
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 450, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.05], Scaled[.1]}, 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 30}], 
 ImageSize -> 450]
```

> [image: output]

Half filled markers which pick up `PlotStyle` and `PlotTheme` automatically:

```
hfm1[name_String, size_ : 9] := Show[
   PolygonMarker[name, Offset@size, {FaceForm[White],
     Dynamic@EdgeForm[{CurrentValue["Color"], AbsoluteThickness[1], Opacity[1]}]}],
   PolygonMarker[name, Offset@size, 
     EdgeForm[None]] /. {x_?Negative, y_?NumericQ} :> {0, y}];

data = Table[{x, BesselJ[k, x]}, {k, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];

ListPlot[data, 
 PlotMarkers -> hfm1 /@ {"UpTriangle", "Square", "Circle"}, 
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 450, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.05], Scaled[.1]}, 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 30}], 
 ImageSize -> 450]
```

> [image: output]

```
hfm2[name_String, size_ : 9] := Show[
   PolygonMarker[name, Offset@size, {
     FaceForm[White],
     Dynamic@EdgeForm[{CurrentValue["Color"], AbsoluteThickness[1], Opacity[1]}]}],
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[None], 
     Replace[RegionDifference[PolygonMarker[name], 
       Rectangle[{-10, -10}, {10, 0}]], 
      p : {x_, y_} :> Offset[size p, {0, 0}], {-2}]}]];

data = Table[{x, BesselJ[k, x]}, {k, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];

ListPlot[data, 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  hfm2 /@ {"Diamond", "Square", "Circle", "RightTriangle"}, 
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 450, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.05], Scaled[.1]}, 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 30}], 
 ImageSize -> 450]
```

> [image: output]

Contrast markers which pick up `PlotStyle` and `PlotTheme` automatically:

```
cfm2[name_String, size_ : 9] := Show[
   PolygonMarker[name, Offset@size, {
     FaceForm[White],
     Dynamic@EdgeForm[{CurrentValue["Color"], AbsoluteThickness[1], Opacity[1]}]}],
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[None], 
     Replace[RegionDifference[
       RegionDifference[PolygonMarker[name], 
        Triangle[{{-10, 10}, {10, 10}, {0, 0}}]], 
       Triangle[{{-10, -10}, {10, -10}, {0, 0}}]], 
      p : {x_, y_} :> Offset[size p, {0, 0}], {-2}]}]];

data = Table[{x, BesselJ[k, x]}, {k, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];

ListPlot[data, 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  cfm2 /@ {"Diamond", "Square", "Circle", "DiagonalFourPointedStar"}, 
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 450, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.05], Scaled[.1]}, 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 30}], ImageSize -> 450]
```

> [image: output]

The package allows the usage of an arbitrary polygon as a plot marker. Here is an auxiliary function that converts a simple glyph into a set of points suitable for `PolygonMarker`:

```
pts[l_String] := 
  First[Cases[
    ImportString[
     ExportString[Style[l, FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 20], "PDF"],
     If[$VersionNumber >= 12.2, {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}, {"PDF", "Pages"}]], 
    c_FilledCurve :> c[[2, 1]], Infinity]];
```

(This conversion is approximate. If the precise conversion is needed one can apply one of the methods described in "[How can I adaptively simplify a curved shape?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137937/280)")

An example of use:

```
ListPlot[ConstantArray[Range[5],7]+Range[0,12,2],PlotStyle->Gray,Joined->True,PlotMarkers->{PolygonMarker[pts["U"],Scaled[0.05],{FaceForm[LightBlue],EdgeForm[Black]}],
  PolygonMarker[pts["S"],Scaled[0.05],{FaceForm[LightBlue],EdgeForm[Black]}],
  PolygonMarker["FivePointedStar",Scaled[0.05],{FaceForm[Red],EdgeForm[Black]}],
  PolygonMarker["FourPointedStar",Scaled[0.05],{FaceForm[Yellow],EdgeForm[Black]}],
  PolygonMarker["DownTriangle",Scaled[0.05],{FaceForm[Green],EdgeForm[Black]}],
  PolygonMarker["DiagonalSquare",Scaled[0.05],{FaceForm[Brown],EdgeForm[Black]}],
  Graphics[{FaceForm[Blue],EdgeForm[Black],Disk[{0,0},Scaled[0.05/Sqrt[\[Pi]]]]}]},PlotRange->{{0,6},{0,18}},ImageSize->450]
```

> [image: output]

Here is an example of a black-and-white plot where the markers overlap considerably, I use here some of the symbols [recommended](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/36908/946) by [William Cleveland](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/%7Ewsc/) in his early works:

```
SeedRandom[11];
ListPlot[RandomReal[{-1,1},{6,20,2}],PlotMarkers->{
  PolygonMarker["Circle",Scaled[0.03],{FaceForm[None],EdgeForm[{Black,Thickness[.008]}]}],
  PolygonMarker["UpTriangle",Scaled[0.03],{FaceForm[None],EdgeForm[{Black,Thickness[.008]}]}],
  PolygonMarker["Cross",Scaled[0.03],{FaceForm[Black],EdgeForm[None]}],
  PolygonMarker[pts["U"],Scaled[0.03],{FaceForm[Black],EdgeForm[None]}],
  PolygonMarker["Sl",Scaled[0.03],{FaceForm[Black],EdgeForm[None]}],
  PolygonMarker[pts["W"],Scaled[0.03],{FaceForm[Black],EdgeForm[None]}]},
 Frame->True,FrameStyle->Black,Axes->False,PlotRangePadding->Scaled[.1],ImageSize->450]
```

> [image: output]

Additional examples and explanations can be found in the following answers:

- [How to make transparent markers without plotted lines going through them?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270194/280)
- [Plot markers where the boundary has the same hue as the body but is darker](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158221/280)
- [Perfect vertical alignment of `PointLegend` markers and their labels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137758/280)
- [Making antisymmetric curvilinear marker "S"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138348/280)
- [How to specify `PlotMarkers` that scale when graphic is resized?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145891/280)
- [Bug in `Export` of figures with `PlotMarkers`?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/250857/280)

Comment: I updated my answer to be compatible with the additions you made in yours, and to correct the placement/shape of the stars and crosses.  (Actually, I just copied your crosses.) I didn't want to apply `N` to my definitions, but I was worried about the performance of your stars, so I defined some slightly different ones that can be represented as `Root` expressions. That seemed like the best compromise between exactness and performance to me.

Comment: Neat! A tiny suggestion: why not have the list of supported shapes be in the package itself, maybe something like `$KnownMarkerShapes`, or a property just like in the curated data functions.

Comment: This is, simply put, great.  Even with v10---the dearth of plot markers can be quite restrictive. +1 this and @OleksandrR.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, I'll attach the list of supported shapes as `PolygonMarker[]` and `PolygonMarker[All]`.

Comment: There seems to be a new way to convert text to outlines in version 10.x.  I just discovered this the other day.  Check the documentation of `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics`: `Show@BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text["A"], _Text]`

Comment: Would it make sense to also add a named version of `Disk[]`, as `"Disk"|"Circle"`, for convenience?  This is the most common type of marker, after all.  To show why I'm asking, [this is how I'm trying to use the package](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eou5z6sy0sllewd/PlotMarkerUsage.nb?dl=0).  The aim is to keep the syntax short and simple.  Sorry about the "enable dynamics" thing, just enable it.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have updated the package with the `"Disk"|"Circle"` plot marker (approximated by 24-gon).

Comment: Should this also work in v10 (.4.1.0)? I followed the link and instructions but `PolygonMarker[]` remains blue (i.e. has not been given any attributes) and none of the above examples work...

Comment: @geordie Yes, please install the package first. Instructions are in the top section: "How to install the package." Then you should evaluate ``Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]`` before using it.

Comment: Adding  `Joined -> False` within `PointLegend[...]` removes the pesky 'wings' from the markers when used in `PlotLegends`.

Comment: This looks amazing, @AlexeyPopkov ! I'm hoping I can get it to work with different opacities, also. I have one question - have you implemented this in 3D also ? I need to make some 3D scatter plots, and I fear that the built in methods might suffer from the same issues, as do the methods for 2D scatter plots.

Comment: Will you keep maintaining the GitHub version after publishing the ResourceFunction?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I already do. Actually I have problems only with updating the `ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"]`, not with the GitHub version. I wish to keep them syncronized and have a tiny pending update, but still can't get published it on WFR (due to the non-standart initial way to submit my item via email, please search my name in the header post [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1794648?p_p_auth=DWW7hig2)).

Answer (score 45):

Fortunately, [Wikipedia has the answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon), as long as we are content to restrict ourselves to non-intersecting closed polygons. This will probably be an acceptable limitation, given that excessively complicated plot markers tend to look slightly distracting anyway.

Because we seek an aesthetic rather than rigorously well defined result, we do not need to be mathematically precise with the way that the polygons are scaled, provided that the centroids are accurate and they all look subjectively about the same size. So, I propose to normalize them by area, and if this does not look quite right, adjustments can be made until a tasteful result is obtained.

We code it in *Mathematica* (please see also [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/oleksandrr/PolygonPlotMarkers) for downloads):

```
BeginPackage["PolygonPlotMarkers`"];

ClearAll[PolygonMarker];

Begin["`Private`"];

ClearAll[ centroidAndScale];
 centroidAndScale[coords : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}] :=
  With[{
    x = coords[[All, 1]], y = coords[[All, 2]],
    i = Range@Length[coords]
    },
   With[{
     xi = x[[i]], yi = y[[i]],
     j = Mod[i + 1, Length[coords], 1]
     },
    With[{
      xj = x[[j]], yj = y[[j]]
      },
     With[{
       area = 1/2 (xi.yj - xj.yi),
       factor = xi yj - xj yi
       },
      With[{
        centroid = 1/(6 area) {(xi + xj).factor, (yi + yj).factor}
        },
       Transpose[{x, y} - centroid]/Sqrt@Abs[area]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ];

ClearAll[ngon];
ngon[n_Integer /; n >= 3, phase_?NumericQ] :=
   centroidAndScale@Table[
    {Sin[2 Pi k/n + phase], Cos[2 Pi k/n + phase]},
    {k, 0, n - 1}
   ];

ClearAll[coords];
coords["UpTriangle"] = ngon[3, 0];
coords["DownTriangle"] = ngon[3, Pi/3];
coords["LeftTriangle"] = ngon[3, Pi/6];
coords["RightTriangle"] = ngon[3, -Pi/6];
coords["DiagonalSquare" | "Diamond"] = ngon[4, 0];
coords["Square"] = ngon[4, Pi/4];
coords["Pentagon"] = ngon[5, 0];
coords["FivePointedStar"] = {
   {0, Root[1296 - 4500 #1^4 + 3125 #1^8 &, 4, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 900 #1^4 + 162000 #1^8 &, 3, 0], Root[1 - 22500 #1^4 + 4050000 #1^8 &, 4, 0]},
   {Root[81 - 1800 #1^4 + 2000 #1^8 &, 4, 0], Root[81 - 9000 #1^4 + 50000 #1^8 &, 3, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 1800 #1^4 + 162000 #1^8 &, 4, 0], Root[1 - 9000 #1^4 + 4050000 #1^8 &, 2, 0]},
   {Root[81 - 900 #1^4 + 2000 #1^8 &, 3, 0], Root[81 - 22500 #1^4 + 50000 #1^8 &, 1, 0]},
   {0, Root[16 - 4500 #1^4 + 253125 #1^8 &, 1, 0]},
   {Root[81 - 900 #1^4 + 2000 #1^8 &, 2, 0], Root[81 - 22500 #1^4 + 50000 #1^8 &, 1, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 1800 #1^4 + 162000 #1^8 &, 1, 0], Root[1 - 9000 #1^4 + 4050000 #1^8 &, 2, 0]},
   {Root[81 - 1800 #1^4 + 2000 #1^8 &, 1, 0], Root[81 - 9000 #1^4 + 50000 #1^8 &, 3, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 900 #1^4 + 162000 #1^8 &, 2, 0], Root[1 - 22500 #1^4 + 4050000 #1^8 &, 4, 0]}
   };
coords["Hexagon"] = ngon[6, 0];
coords["SixPointedStar"] = {
   {0, Sqrt[2/3]}, {1/(2 Sqrt[6]), 1/(2 Sqrt[2])}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[6]},
   {1/Sqrt[6], 0}, {1/Sqrt[2], -(1/Sqrt[6])}, {1/(2 Sqrt[6]), -1/(2 Sqrt[2])},
   {0, -Sqrt[2/3]}, {-1/(2 Sqrt[6]), -1/(2 Sqrt[2])}, {-(1/Sqrt[2]), -(1/Sqrt[6])},
   {-(1/Sqrt[6]), 0}, {-(1/Sqrt[2]), 1/Sqrt[6]}, {-1/(2 Sqrt[6]), 1/(2 Sqrt[2])}
   };
coords["SixfoldPinwheel"] = {
   {0, Root[-25 + 27 #1^4 &, 2, 0]},
   {Root[-1 + 75 #1^4 &, 2, 0], Root[-1 + 675 #1^4 &, 2, 0]},
   {Root[-25 + 48 #1^4 &, 2, 0], Root[-25 + 432 #1^4 &, 2, 0]},
   {Root[-1 + 75 #1^4 &, 2, 0], Root[-1 + 675 #1^4 &, 1, 0]},
   {Root[-25 + 48 #1^4 &, 2, 0], Root[-25 + 432 #1^4 &, 1, 0]},
   {0, Root[-16 + 675 #1^4 &, 1, 0]}, {0, Root[-25 + 27 #1^4 &, 1, 0]},
   {Root[-1 + 75 #1^4 &, 1, 0], Root[-1 + 675 #1^4 &, 1, 0]},
   {Root[-25 + 48 #1^4 &, 1, 0], Root[-25 + 432 #1^4 &, 1, 0]},
   {Root[-1 + 75 #1^4 &, 1, 0], Root[-1 + 675 #1^4 &, 2, 0]},
   {Root[-25 + 48 #1^4 &, 1, 0], Root[-25 + 432 #1^4 &, 2, 0]},
   {0, Root[-16 + 675 #1^4 &, 2, 0]}
   };
coords["EightPointedStar"] = {
   {0, Root[1 - 16 #1^4 + 32 #1^8 &, 4, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 2048 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 3, 0], Root[1 - 10240 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 4, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 64 #1^4 + 512 #1^8 &, 4, 0], Root[1 - 64 #1^4 + 512 #1^8 &, 4, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 10240 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 4, 0], Root[1 - 2048 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 3, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 16 #1^4 + 32 #1^8 &, 4, 0], 0},
   {Root[1 - 10240 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 4, 0], Root[1 - 2048 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 2, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 64 #1^4 + 512 #1^8 &, 4, 0], Root[1 - 64 #1^4 + 512 #1^8 &, 1, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 2048 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 3, 0], Root[1 - 10240 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 1, 0]},
   {0, Root[1 - 16 #1^4 + 32 #1^8 &, 1, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 2048 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 2, 0], Root[1 - 10240 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 1, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 64 #1^4 + 512 #1^8 &, 1, 0], Root[1 - 64 #1^4 + 512 #1^8 &, 1, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 10240 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 1, 0], Root[1 - 2048 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 2, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 16 #1^4 + 32 #1^8 &, 1, 0], 0},
   {Root[1 - 10240 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 1, 0], Root[1 - 2048 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 3, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 64 #1^4 + 512 #1^8 &, 1, 0], Root[1 - 64 #1^4 + 512 #1^8 &, 4, 0]},
   {Root[1 - 2048 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 2, 0], Root[1 - 10240 #1^4 + 524288 #1^8 &, 4, 0]}
   };
coords["EightfoldPinwheel"] = {
   {0, Root[-1 + 2 #1^4 &, 2, 0]},
   {Root[-1 + 128 #1^4 &, 2, 0], Root[-1 + 128 #1^4 &, 2, 0]},
   {Root[-1 + 8 #1^4 &, 2, 0], Root[-1 + 8 #1^4 &, 2, 0]},
   {Root[-1 + 32 #1^4 &, 2, 0], 0},
   {Root[-1 + 2 #1^4 &, 2, 0], 0},
   {Root[-1 + 128 #1^4 &, 2, 0], Root[-1 + 128 #1^4 &, 1, 0]},
   {Root[-1 + 8 #1^4 &, 2, 0], Root[-1 + 8 #1^4 &, 1, 0]},
   {0, Root[-1 + 32 #1^4 &, 1, 0]},
   {0, Root[-1 + 2 #1^4 &, 1, 0]},
   {Root[-1 + 128 #1^4 &, 1, 0], Root[-1 + 128 #1^4 &, 1, 0]},
   {Root[-1 + 8 #1^4 &, 1, 0], Root[-1 + 8 #1^4 &, 1, 0]},
   {Root[-1 + 32 #1^4 &, 1, 0], 0},
   {Root[-1 + 2 #1^4 &, 1, 0], 0},
   {Root[-1 + 128 #1^4 &, 1, 0], Root[-1 + 128 #1^4 &, 2, 0]},
   {Root[-1 + 8 #1^4 &, 1, 0], Root[-1 + 8 #1^4 &, 2, 0]},
   {0, Root[-1 + 32 #1^4 &, 2, 0]}
   };
coords["Cross"] = 
  centroidAndScale@With[{a = 1/6}, 
    Join @@ NestList[#.{{0, -1}, {1, 0}} &, {{-a, 1}, {a, 1}, {a, a}}, 3]
   ];
coords["DiagonalCross"] = coords["Cross"].RotationMatrix[Pi/4];

PolygonMarker[name_String, size_?NumericQ, 
   offset : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} : {0, 0}] :=
  Polygon@Transpose[Transpose[size coords[name]] + offset];
PolygonMarker[name_String, Scaled[size_?NumericQ], 
   offset : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} : {0, 0}] :=
  Polygon[Scaled[size #, offset] & /@ coords[name]];
PolygonMarker[coords : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}, size_?NumericQ, 
   offset : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} : {0, 0}] :=
  Polygon@Transpose[Transpose[size centroidAndScale[coords]] + offset];
PolygonMarker[coords : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}, 
   Scaled[size_?NumericQ], 
   offset : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} : {0, 0}] :=
  Polygon[Scaled[size #, offset] & /@ centroidAndScale[coords]];

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

Here, the coordinates of the polygons other than the *n*-gons have come from the font glyphs after converting them to outlines, centroiding, and scaling.

The polygon sizes can be given either in absolute or scaled forms, and the results look okay:

```
Graphics[{
  FaceForm[Blue], EdgeForm@Directive[Red, Thickness[0.02]],
  PolygonMarker["DiagonalCross", Scaled[0.2], {0.5, 0.5}],
  FaceForm[Green], EdgeForm@Directive[Black, Thickness[0.02]],
  PolygonMarker["UpTriangle", Scaled[0.2], {-0.5, 0.5}],
  FaceForm[Yellow], EdgeForm@Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.02]],
  PolygonMarker["FivePointedStar", Scaled[0.2], {-0.5, -0.5}],
  FaceForm[Black], EdgeForm@Directive[Purple, Thickness[0.02]],
  PolygonMarker["SixfoldPinwheel", Scaled[0.2], {0.5, -0.5}]
  }, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
 GridLines -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {-0.5, 0.5}}
 ]
```

[image: plot of four of the polygons]

Here are all of them together:

```
shapes = {
   "UpTriangle", "DownTriangle", "LeftTriangle",
   "RightTriangle", "Cross", "DiagonalCross",
   "Diamond", "Square", "Pentagon",
   "FivePointedStar", "Hexagon", "SixPointedStar",
   "SixfoldPinwheel", "EightPointedStar", "EightfoldPinwheel"
   };
Graphics[{
    FaceForm[Hue@Random[]], EdgeForm@Directive[Black, Thickness[0.03]],
    PolygonMarker[#, Scaled[1]]
    }, ImageSize -> 40] & /@ shapes
```

[image: all named plot markers together]

Let's check it as an actual plot marker:

```
ListPlot[
 ConstantArray[Range[5], 4] + Range[0, 6, 2],
 PlotStyle -> Black, Joined -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> {
   Graphics[{FaceForm[Red], EdgeForm[Red], 
     PolygonMarker["FivePointedStar", Scaled[0.05]]}],
   Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Green], 
     PolygonMarker["UpTriangle", Scaled[0.05]]}],
   Graphics[{FaceForm[Blue], EdgeForm[Blue], 
     PolygonMarker["DiagonalSquare", Scaled[0.05]]}],
   Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[0.03]]}]
   },
 PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, All}
]
```

[image: polygonal PlotMarkers used on a ListPlot]

Everything seems good. It may not look absolutely perfect on-screen, because graphics objects are [snapped to the pixel grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/graphics-elements-do-not-line-up-perfectly-in-exported-pdfs) for display. But exporting the resulting plot as e.g. a PDF file will demonstrate that the placement is correct.

Comment: Excellent!  Off-center `PlotMarkers` have been irking me intermittently (but reliably) .

Comment: Notes: I implemented the shoelace method for area [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22587), and a procedure for the centroid [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7715). Could be useful… :)

Comment: The only downside: now I'll have to redo quite a few figures right away.

Comment: @J.M. your formulations are considerably more elegant than mine. I suppose that's what comes of knowing where these expressions come from, rather than just copying a result from Wikipedia out of sheer frustration.

Comment: @J.M. on the other hand, my formulation evaluates in about one sixth of the time for a 1 million point polygon. Of course it's open to question whether it is sensible to consider such a polygon anyway...

Comment: Probably in the case of taking areas/centroids of [countries](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3695), I guess. :) (P.S. IOU one upvote.)

Comment: @J.M. in that case, I updated the post with a slightly improved version. Maybe worth noting that it is also compilable, and it achieves a fair speedup by doing so. Could be useful in case someone wants to use the countries of the world as plot markers? (But the rendering will be a slow process.)

Comment: @OleksandrR. Very clever and clear approach (+1)! But I must note that all manual definitions (`"FivePointedStar"`, `"SixPointedStar"`, `"Cross"`, `"DiagonalCross"`) are not quite correct: they are distorted a bit and/or shifted a bit from the center. For example, why the top point of the `"FivePointedStar"` is at `x = 1/7260` instead of `x = 0`? For `"FivePointedStar"` I suggest to start from `Polygon[Flatten[Table[{{0,1},{Sin[Pi/10] Tan[Pi/5],Sin[Pi/10]}}.RotationMatrix[2n Pi/5],{n,0,4}],1]]`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. For the `"SixPointedStar"` you could start from `Polygon[Flatten[Table[{{0,1},{1/(2 Sqrt[3]),1/2}}.RotationMatrix[2n Pi/6],{n,0,5}],1]]`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. For `"Cross"`: `Polygon[With[{a=1/10},Join@@NestList[#.{{0,-1},{1,0}}&,{{-a,1},{a,1},{a,a}},3]]]`, for `"DiagonalCross"`: `Polygon[With[{a=1/10},Join@@NestList[#.{{0,-1},{1,0}}&,{{-a,1},{a,1},{a,a}}.RotationMatrix[Pi/4],3]]]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thanks! It is because after converting to outlines I used `Rationalize` on the result (although the font outlines also may not be perfect; I didn't check these). I thought that the error of $< 10^{-3}$ would not be significant, but you are right, it is not strictly correct. I will see if I have time later on to update the definitions. Or you are welcome to edit the post if you like. Thanks again.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I ended up with completely reimplemented core of your package, so I decided to post it as [separate answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094/280).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov it's very nice! Thanks for the extra shape ideas. Actually, the reason I didn't update the answer yet is due to trouble with the star coordinates. They end up being extremely large irrational expressions that get even larger after centroiding and scaling, which it doesn't seem a good idea to use in graphics. So I had been thinking about how best to make a star whose vertices are "rounder" numbers.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov and Oleksandr: Have you considered putting this on GitHub or other similar site?  It would be easier for us to keep it up to date and it would also be easier to download the package (no copy & paste).

Comment: @Szabolcs I have added the option to load and install my package from GitHub (see my answer).

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks. I am not very good at keeping the GitHub up to date, so it is just as well you seem to be quite good at prompting me!

Comment: Do we have an easy way to allow these to pick up the `PlotStyle`, in particular the *colour*, without having to double- or triple-specify it for the line, the markers and the legend?

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't know but I have a feeling this may have been asked before in a different context. If you can find the question, please link it here. And if not, it is a good topic for a new question.

Comment: @Szabolcs actually, it was even suggested by the site as a related question. Here: [(56327)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56327/how-to-make-plotmarkers-constructed-from-graphics-track-plot-style). Although undocumented, this method does seem to [work fine](http://i.imgur.com/JFvbDp1.png). I am not sure about the case with the legend, though.

Answer (score 27):

Here is an alternative answer. Of course, since you answered your own question, you may not need this. But I think the following is a viable alternative that may end up looking comparable, and has additional dynamic features.

Instead of `ListPlot`, just use [`BubbleChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BubbleChart.html).

```
data = ConstantArray[Range[5], 4] + Range[0, 6, 2];

newData = Map[MapIndexed[Join[#2, {#, 1}] &, #] &, data];

Show[BubbleChart[newData, BubbleSizes -> {.05, .05}, 
  ChartElementFunction -> {ChartElementDataFunction["MarkerBubble", 
     "Shape" -> "Diamond", "Filled" -> False],
    ChartElementDataFunction["MarkerBubble", "Shape" -> "Square", 
     "Filled" -> True],
    ChartElementDataFunction["PolyhedronBubble", 
     "Polyhedron" -> "Octahedron"], 
    ChartElementDataFunction["MarkerBubble", "Shape" -> "CirclePlus", 
     "Filled" -> False]}],
 ListLinePlot[data]]
```

[image: bubbles]

This example with a lot of customizations shows that the marker alignment in `BubbleChart` is quite reliable when you use  one of the `"MarkerBubble"` chart elements. The alignment can still look bad if you use bubbles that are not of the type `"MarkerBubble"`.

Of course, the variety of shapes is more limited, but there is a special palette called **Chart Element Schemes** in the menu bar, which lets you choose the appearance interactively. And of course you can also design your own markers, analogously to `ListPlot`. I did something along those lines [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7412/245).

Comment: Good suggestion. I hadn't considered this. Thanks.

Comment: It is worth to add that we have also built-in (but undocumented) `ChartElementData["PlotMarkers"]` as uncovered in [this answer by rcollyer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95298/280).

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyPopkov, I just looked at that answer and I like it...