# Change or force plot legend marker symbols

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I am wondering if there is a way to force the plot legend symbol for each respective plot. I am currently using a package created by AlexeyPopkov, which corrects the off-centre plot marker issue very nicely. For reference the link to the package is:
[How can we make publication-quality PlotMarkers without version 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84857/how-can-we-make-publication-quality-plotmarkers-without-version-10/85094#85094)

```
Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]
PLOT = ListLinePlot[DATA, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin], Axes -> False, BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.999], ImageSize -> 400, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thin], PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{FaceForm[Black], EdgeForm[Black], PolygonMarker["Circle", Scaled[0.03]]}]}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{Style["Plot Legend Label", Black,10]}, {Left, Top}, Pane[#, 450, Alignment -> Left] &]];
```

However the new plot markers do not appear in the plot legend, only the plot lines. Is there a way to force a plot marker onto a plot legend specifically using `Graphics`? I tried using `PlotLegends->Automatic` but nothing renders at all in this case.

```
Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]
PLOT = ListLinePlot[DATA, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin], Axes -> False, BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.999], ImageSize -> 400, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin], PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{FaceForm[Black], EdgeForm[Black], PolygonMarker["Circle", Scaled[0.03]]}]}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Cheers all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as simple as follows using *Mathematica* 10 or higher:

```
Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]

fm[name_, size_: 7] := 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[], PolygonMarker[name, Offset[size]]}, AlignmentPoint -> {0, 0}]

ListPlot[Table[Accumulate@RandomReal[1, 10] + i, {i, 3}], 
 PlotMarkers -> fm /@ {"Triangle", "Square", "Diamond"}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 20}]]
```

> [image: plot]

Note that the sizes of the plot markers in the plot and in the legend are identical because the `Offset` size specification is used (possible size specifications are documented in the "Description of the package" section of the [original answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094/280)).

Comment: Managed to finally get this working! Thanks for all the help nice work with the `PolygonPlotMarkers` Package - it's great!

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about `` PolygonPlotMarkers` `` package, so I am presenting a general solution. You can always define your own `Graphics` as markers. For example, I use here regular polygons

```
col = {Red, Blue, Green, Orange, Black};
marker[col_, n_] := Graphics[{col, 
                 Polygon[{Cos[2 Pi #/n], Sin[2 Pi #/n]} & /@ Range[n]]}
                 ,ImageSize -> 10]

ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1, {5, 5}], PlotStyle -> col,
  PlotMarkers -> Table[marker[col[[n]], n + 2], {n, 5}], 
  PlotLegends -> True]
```

[image]

You can use any figure or text or symbol for the markers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's a nice alternative solution!