# Extract all unique characters and number of their appearance from string?

Tags: string-manipulation

Consider a string containing ASCII characters (letters, digits, symbols). For example:

```
mystr="AHjksHslknHKJBSEW-QLM +sdfkjbKJGEmn";
```

How do I most conveniently break this string into a list of unique characters contained in the string along with the number of appearance of each character?

Comment: How about `StringPartition` and `Tally`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given:

```
mystr = "AHjksHslknHKJBSEW-QLM +sdfkjbKJGEmn";
```

From version 10 onward, we can get a count of occurrences for each character like this:

```
count = mystr // Characters // Counts

(* <| "A" -> 1, "H" -> 3, "j" -> 2, "k" -> 3, "s" -> 3, "l" -> 1,
      "n" -> 2, "K" -> 2, "J" -> 2, "B" -> 1, "S" -> 1, "E" -> 2,
      "W" -> 1, "-" -> 1, "Q" -> 1, "L" -> 1, "M" -> 1, " " -> 1,
      "+" -> 1, "d" -> 1, "f" -> 1, "b" -> 1, "G" -> 1, "m" -> 1 |> *)
```

If we want these in order, we can sort:

```
count // Sort

(* <| "-" -> 1, "+" -> 1, " " -> 1, "A" -> 1, "b" -> 1, "B" -> 1,
      "d" -> 1, "f" -> 1, "G" -> 1, "l" -> 1, "L" -> 1, "m" -> 1,
      "M" -> 1, "Q" -> 1, "S" -> 1, "W" -> 1, "E" -> 2, "j" -> 2,
      "J" -> 2, "K" -> 2, "n" -> 2, "H" -> 3, "k" -> 3, "s" -> 3 |> *)
```

We can also use `count` to obtain the counts of individual characters:

```
count["A"]
(* 1 *)

count["H"]
(* 3 *)
```

**Prior to Version 10**

Prior to version 10, we can use `Tally` and `Rule` to get the same effect:

```
count2 = mystr // Characters // Tally  // Rule @@@ # &

(* { "A" -> 1, "H" -> 3, "j" -> 2, "k" -> 3, "s" -> 3, "l" -> 1,
     "n" -> 2, "K" -> 2, "J" -> 2, "B" -> 1, "S" -> 1, "E" -> 2,
     "W" -> 1, "-" -> 1, "Q" -> 1, "L" -> 1, "M" -> 1, " " -> 1,
     "+" -> 1, "d" -> 1, "f" -> 1, "b" -> 1, "G" -> 1, "m" -> 1 } *)

"E" /. count2
(* 2 *)
```

**CharacterCounts (Version 10.1+)**

As @yode points out in a comment, version 10.1 introduced the helper function `LetterCounts`.  It also introduced `CharacterCounts`:

```
mystr // CharacterCounts

(* <| "s" -> 3, "k" -> 3, "H" -> 3, "n" -> 2, "K" -> 2, "J" -> 2,
      "j" -> 2, "E" -> 2, "W" -> 1, "S" -> 1, "Q" -> 1, "M" -> 1,
      "m" -> 1, "L" -> 1, "l" -> 1, "G" -> 1, "f" -> 1, "d" -> 1,
      "B" -> 1, "b" -> 1, "A" -> 1, " " -> 1, "+" -> 1, "-" -> 1 |> *)
```

Note that the result is sorted in descending order by frequency.  The documentation does not mention this fact, but an inspection of the definition of `CharacterCounts` reveals that it is intentional.  `CharacterCounts` also supports the `IgnoreCase` keyword and counting n-grams:

```
CharacterCounts[mystr, 2, IgnoreCase -> True]

(* <| "ah" -> 1, "hj" -> 1, "jk" -> 1, "ks" -> 1, "sh" -> 1,
      "hs" -> 1, "sl" -> 1, "lk" -> 1, "kn" -> 1, "nh" -> 1,
      "hk" -> 1, "kj" -> 3, "jb" -> 2, "bs" -> 1, "se" -> 1,
      "ew" -> 1, "w-" -> 1, "-q" -> 1, "ql" -> 1, "lm" -> 1,
      "m " -> 1, " +" -> 1, "+s" -> 1, "sd" -> 1, "df" -> 1,
      "fk" -> 1, "bk" -> 1, "jg" -> 1, "ge" -> 1, "em" -> 1,
      "mn" -> 1 |> *)
```

Comment: Is that a language?

Comment: Have you seen `LetterCounts`?

Comment: @yode No, I hadn't. Its sibling function `CharacterCounts` is particularly relevant.  I have added a section that discusses it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

An efficient and straightforward approach is to use `Characters` in combination with `Tally`:

```
mystr = "AHjksHslknHKJBSEW-QLM +sdfkjbKJGEmnm";
counts = Tally@Characters[mystr]
```

> ```
> {{"A", 1}, {"H", 3}, {"j", 2}, {"k", 3}, {"s", 3}, {"l", 1}, {"n", 2}, {"K", 2}, {"J", 2}, 
>  {"B", 1}, {"S", 1}, {"E", 2}, {"W", 1}, {"-", 1}, {"Q", 1}, {"L", 1}, {"M", 1}, {" ", 1}, 
>  {"+", 1}, {"d", 1}, {"f", 1}, {"b", 1}, {"G", 1}, {"m", 2}}
> ```

Timing comparison (version 11.0.0):

```
counts1 = Tally@Characters[#] &;
counts2 = Tally@StringSplit[#, ""] &;
counts3 = Counts@Characters[#] &;
counts4 = Module[{t = Tally[ToCharacterCode[#]]}, 
    Transpose[{FromCharacterCode@Transpose[{t[[All, 1]]}], t[[All, 2]]}]] &;
counts5 = MapAt[FromCharacterCode, Tally[ToCharacterCode[#]], {All, 1}] &;

mystr[n_] := StringJoin@RandomChoice[CharacterRange[" ", "~"], n];

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

benchmarks = Benchmark[#, mystr, Array[2^# &, 22, 6], TimeConstraint -> 100] & /@ 
   {counts1, counts2, counts3, counts4, counts5};
```

For better readability I use a set of plot markers which tolerate overlapping from my [`PolygonPlotMarkers` package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094/280):

```
Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]

ListLogLogPlot[benchmarks, ImageSize -> 600, PlotMarkers -> {
   Graphics[{FaceForm[Magenta], EdgeForm[], PolygonMarker["Circle", Offset[7]]}], 
   Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Brown, Opacity[1], AbsoluteThickness[2]}], 
     PolygonMarker["Square", Offset[8]]}], 
   Graphics[{FaceForm[RGBColor[0.34, 0.4, 0.62]], EdgeForm[], 
     PolygonMarker["TripleCross", Offset[7]]}], 
   Graphics[{FaceForm[Red], EdgeForm[], PolygonMarker["FourPointedStar", Offset[9]]}], 
   Graphics[{FaceForm[Blue], EdgeForm[None], PolygonMarker["DiagonalCross", Offset[7]]}]},
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 16,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[{"counts1", "counts2", "counts3", "counts4", "counts5"}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 15,
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 7] &)], Scaled[{.85, .3}]]]
```

> [image: plot]

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you mean?

```
mystr = "AHjksHslknHKJBSEW-QLM +sdfkjbKJGEmnm"; 
lst = StringSplit[mystr, ""];
Tally@lst
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If you `Union` prior to `Tally` the count will always be one for each character. Try `lst = Union@Tally@StringSplit[mystr, ""]`

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you, I was making this clarification while you were writing the comment. I added 2 cases. But the question asked for `list of unique characters contained in the string along with the number of appearance of each character` and so I first did exactly as it asked :)

Comment: I still think you want `Union@Tally@lst` or more simply just `Sort@Tally@lst` since the `Union` is just sorting because the first part of the elements of the `Tally` are distinct.

Answer (score 4):

This should be quite a bit faster than solutions posted so far, and I'd guess order(s) of magnitude faster for large strings:

```
counts=Module[{t = Tally[ToCharacterCode[#]]}, 
              Transpose[{FromCharacterCode@Transpose[{t[[All, 1]]}],t[[All, 2]]}]]&;
```

Use:

```
results=counts@mystr
```

Comment: `MapAt[FromCharacterCode, Tally[ToCharacterCode[#]], {All, 1}] &` gives almost the same performance (version 11.0.0).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: Yep, pretty close.