# How to specify PlotMarkers that scale when graphic is resized?

Tags: plotting, graphics, scaling

A `ListPlot`'s default markers resize as the plot is resized.

```
ListPlot[{{{1, 1}}, {{2, 2}}, {{3, 3}}}]
```

However, if you specify custom `PlotMarkers` that use `Scaled` for their dimensions then these markers do not resize as the plot is resized.

```
ListPlot[{{{1, 1}}, {{2, 2}}, {{3, 3}}},
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics /@ {
    Circle[{0, 0}, Scaled[.1]],
    Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.1]],
    Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.1], {0, 4}]}]
```

How do you specify `PlotMarkers` that resize when the plot is resized?

A solution that does not use `Dynamic` is preferred.  I am thinking that there must be a means to do this since without `Dynamic` it works on the default markers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to specify scaled sizes of the plot markers explicitly via the `PlotMarkers` option. Citing the Documentation page for [`PlotMarkers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html) (under the "Details" section):

> With `PlotMarkers -> {g, s}`, the object `g` is scaled so that one unit of its coordinates corresponds to a fraction `s` of the width of the whole graphic.

This statement is slightly incorrect because the specification `PlotMarkers -> {g, s}` (where `g` has `Head` `Graphics`) is directly translated by `ListPlot` into

```
Inset[g, pos, Automatic, Scaled[{s, s}]]
```

(where `pos` is coordinates of a datapoint) what can be seen from `InpuForm` of generated graphics:

```
First@Cases[
   ListPlot[{0, 1, 3, 4, 5}, PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics[Disk[]], .1}}],
   _Inset, -1] /. _Graphics -> g
```

> ```
> Inset[g, {1., 0.}, Automatic, Scaled[{0.1, 0.1}]]
> ```

So a more correct statement would be:

> With `PlotMarkers -> {g, s}`, the object `g` with head `Graphics` is scaled so that its size is equal to a fraction `s` of the whole plotting range.

---

For the case in the question a solution may be written as follows:

```
ListPlot[{{{1, 1}}, {{2, 2}}, {{3, 3}}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, All}, 
 PlotMarkers -> ({Graphics[#], .1} & /@ {Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Disk[{0, 0}, 1], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, 4}]})]
```

> [image: output]

Note that you don't have to use `Scaled` radii/coordinates in this case (although you can if you have a good reason for this).

Note also that if you wrap your primitives by `List`, then they will be styled automatically according to `PlotStyle` option:

```
ListPlot[{{{1, 1}}, {{2, 2}}, {{3, 3}}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, All}, 
 PlotMarkers -> ({Graphics[{#}], .1} & /@ {Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Disk[{0, 0}, 1], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, 4}]})]
```

> [image: output]

Comment: This is excellent. I missed this syntax option. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a post-processing approach:

```
ListPlot[{{{1, 1}}, {{2, 2}}, {{3, 3}}},
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics /@ {
    Circle[{0, 0}, Scaled[.1]],
    Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.1]],
    Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.1], {0, 4}]}
 ] /. Inset[g_Graphics, pos_] :> Inset[g, pos, Automatic, Scaled[1]]
```

Explanation. By default the inset is rendered with fixed size and your `Scaled` radius is calculated relative to this fixed size. When we specify the size of inset to be `Scaled[1]` we make the size of the inset equal to the size of the whole plotting range of the enclosing graphics. As the result when you resize the enclosing graphics (by the mouse or by changing the `ImageSize` option) the inset is scaled with it.

Comment: Good workaround. (+1) Do you think this is a bug with `Scaled`?

Comment: @Edmund No, `Inset` behaves here exactly as described on its Documentation page: your radius `Scaled[.1]` is calculated relative to the size of `Inset`, not relative to the size of the whole plot. My solution is to make the size of `Inset` be equal to the size of the whole plot.