# How to use standard plot markers

Tags: plotting

I cannot find a list of standard plot markers (square, trinagle, dot, circle, disk, cross, plus,  ...) and how to use them.

Fore example I can access a self made cross, by:

```
cross = Graphics[{Blue, Line[{{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}}}]}];

ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, PlotMarkers -> {cross, 0.1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5}, {0, 2.5}}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Is this symbol and the others in the list predefined, and how can I use them in a plot?

UPDATE:

Following Carl Wolls proposal I tried:

```
p = Style[Graphics`PlotMarkers[][[6, 1]], FontFamily -> "Times"];

circle = Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 1]];

range = Range[0.9, 1.15, 0.1];

ListPlot[{{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{p, 300}, {cross, 0.05}, {circle, 0.3}}, GridLines -> {range, range}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.8, 1.15}, {0.8, 1.15}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

As you see the symbol `p` is still not centered around the data point `{1,1}`, whereas `circle` and `cross` are correct.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84857).

Comment: @J. M. Thank you, this link is very helpfull ... so there is no symbol predefined in 11.1.1?

Comment: Look under the `Palettes` menu for `Special Characters`

Comment: From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6038297/8424426)  can try `Graphics\`PlotMarkers[]`

Comment: @John Joseph M. Carrasco: This is interesting, but I found out that e.g. `Graphics\`PlotMarkers[][[1, 1]]`is unfortunately not centered ... the same problem for all other markers ...

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: I tested a few special characters and none of them is really centered. For scientific presentation they should be centered around 0 as the `cross` in my example.

Comment: You could try using ``Style[Graphics`PlotMarkers[][[1, 1]], FontFamily->"Times"]`` instead.

Comment: @Carl Woll: see my update ... the same probe occurs for all markers in this set ... also for `... PlotMarkers[][[1, 1]], FontFamily -> "Times"];`

Comment: I wouldn't use the standard markers exactly because they are not properly centered (that's because they use font glyphs instead of graphics primitives).  I usually use what's in JM's link.

Comment: I think the problem of defining well centered markers may deserve its own question, as it will be hard to find if titled *"How to use standard plot markers"*. Or probably this question could be renamed and make it about that.