# Cross plot markers in a ListPlot?

Tags: plotting

How can I obtain crosses as plot markers in a ListPlot?

I know how to obtain circles, disks, squares, using `Graphics`, like `PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Red, Thick, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 10]}`. But I can't think of any way to obtain a cross this way, other than actually drawing the cross, which seems overkill. Is there a simpler way? I just need some advice on the best way to do this without too much work.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094)?

Comment: `ListPlot[{1, 2, 3, 4}, PlotMarkers -> "+"]` ?

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 Nice! That works. To get some more fine control, you can do something like `PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Black, FontSize -> 20, Text["+"]}]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `PlotMarkers -> "+"` is not a good solution, because the text is aligned with its foot at the point, not the centre of the cross.

If you want the centre of the cross to have a precise position in the plot, you can use:

```
cross = Graphics[{Line[{{-1,0},{1,0}}], Line[{{0,-1},{0,1}}]}] 
ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {cross,0.05}]
```

Comment: Hi Jan, Welcome to Mma.SE. thanks for making your first contribution to Mma.SE. Be sure to take the [tour]. The site depends on participation, and I'm glad to see your first activity was to share what you have learned and give an answer. Your answer was flagged, as a new user, so I was checking everything was fine, and as it is, I can only welcome and thank you. (+1).

Answer (score 2):

This would be a simple solution:

```
ListPlot[{1, 2, 3, 4}, PlotMarkers -> Style["+", {Black, FontSize -> 20}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively: `ListPlot[{1, 2, 3, 4}, PlotMarkers -> Style["✚", Medium]]`.

Comment: @J.M. that would be a more aesthetic solution, I edited mine