# Plot markers where the boundary has the same hue as the body but is darker

Tags: plotting, visualization, marker

I was using Mathematica v11 to generate some figures and was wondering how to obtain plot markers like the one shown in the figure below:

[image: From: https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2628]

From: https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2628

The key attribute of these markers is that they consist of a solid boundary with a semi-transparent fill of the *same* color. However, following the procedure outlined in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84857/how-can-we-make-publication-quality-plotmarkers-without-version-10) question generates markers that are either completely solid or completely hollow (i.e., white-filled).

Any suggestions to create the markers shown above would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an undocumented trick:  `CurrentValue["Color"]` retrieves the current colour at a certain position within a `Graphics` expression.  I learned this from @halirutan in a post that I am too lazy to look up now.

If you have the current colour, you can do with it as you wish: you can inject it into an `EdgeForm` or you can make it lighter by `Blend`ing it with `White`.

```
Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]

Clear[marker]
marker[name_String, size_: 9] := 
 Graphics[{
   Dynamic@EdgeForm[CurrentValue["Color"]], 
   Dynamic@FaceForm@Blend[{White, CurrentValue["Color"]}, 0.25], 
   PolygonMarker[name, 1]}, ImageSize -> size]

data = Table[{x, BesselJ[k, x]}, {k, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];

ListPlot[data, 
 PlotMarkers -> marker /@ {"UpTriangle", "Square", "Circle"},
 Joined -> True,
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

To fully understand why this solution works, you should know that when `Graphics[{foo}]` is passed as a plot marker, `ListPlot` will change it to `Graphics[{color, foo}]` to apply a certain colour.

(I don't remember which version of PolygonPlotMarkers I have installed at the moment. If you have the other one, some tweaks may be required.)

Comment: Is something like ``Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]`` missing?