# PlotMarkers - are there default common shapes available?

Tags: plotting

I'm generating a ListPlot and wanting to use Open Markers like [in the 2nd example here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html), however I don't want the word "Open Markers" - I just want open circles/diamonds etc.  Are there default shapes you can still access with mathematica like this, or do you need to create all your own markers and define directly?

I know I can create all my own markers and make it anything I want, but I was hoping for some simple defaults that you can easily access.  I've tried using `Circle`, `Diamond`, `Square` because those auto-completed, but I just get the words, not the symbols.

e.g.

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"]
```

I am using v11.3.0

Comment: `\[EmptySquare]`  `\[EmptyCircle]` `\[EmptyDiamond]`

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84857/how-can-we-make-publication-quality-plotmarkers-without-version-10

Comment: Note that `PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"` was added in version 12.  It does what the OP wants but is not available in V11.3.

Answer (score 7):

You can get markers using `` Charting`CommonDump`GraphicsOpenPlotMarkers ``:

```
{circle, uptriangle, diamond, square, downtriangle} = 
   Charting`CommonDump`GraphicsOpenPlotMarkers[][[;;5]];

ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {uptriangle, circle, square}]
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work in V12 with the warning   Set::shape: Lists {circle,uptriangle,diamond,square,downtriangle} and Charting`CommonDump`GraphicsOpenPlotMarkers[] are not the same shape.

Comment: @Okkes, it works on Wolfram Cloud (v12). You can try ``{circle,uptriangle,diamond,square,downtriangle} = ChartingCommonDumpGraphicsOpenPlotMarkers[][[;;5]]``

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci It works in V12 for me (Mac), but it does not work in V11.3, the version the OP has.  BTW, `PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"` does the same thing.

Comment: My bad. I guess the issue was backtick was missing when I pasted it.

Comment: It looks like you need to generate a `ListPlot` before this command will work, at least in v13.0.

Comment: I was looking how to get the default ones and ended up here so in case someone follows the same path: `Charting\`CommonDump\`GraphicsPlotMarkers` likewise gives the default filled in ones.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to get to the open markers on V11.3, which start with the 6th plot marker in the standard V11.3 sequence of markers:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> RotateLeft[Graphics`PlotMarkers[], 5]]
```

[image]

Note: V12 introduced `PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"` (and `` Charting`CommonDump`GraphicsOpenPlotMarkers[] ``, which @kglr's answer shows), which is a simpler way to get the desired result; however, it is unavailabe to the OP.