# Open plot markers without background

Tags: plotting, marker

I want to use differently shaped and sized open plot markers to visualize overlapping data more clearly in `ListPlot`.

To this end I extracted plot markers according to the method proposed in [PlotMarkers - are there default common shapes available?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201960/45020). I rescale them appropriately using:

```
Offset[{a_, b_}] :> Offset[scale {a, b}]
```

(Probably not the smartest way but it works here.)

However, there is a clear problem when using these. Intersecting lines of different markers do not show up. The open shape seems to be filled in with a background. Although that is not exactly what is happening because if I put a background behind the plot this is shown through the open plot markers.

How do I get differently shaped re-sizable open plot markers that are see-through in their interior?

Below is an image showing the "wrong" overlapping behavior that I want to avoid. I would like the shape of one plotmarker to continue under the other.

[image: Wrong overlapping behaviour]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can insert `FaceForm[]` before `Disk` and `Polygon` primitives:

```
{circle, uptriangle, diamond, square, downtriangle} = 
   Charting`CommonDump`GraphicsOpenPlotMarkers[][[;;5]];

scale = 4;
markers = {uptriangle, circle, square} /. {p : _Disk | _Polygon :> {FaceForm[], p}, 
     Offset[{a_, b_}] :> Offset[scale {a, b}]};

scale = 4;
ListPlot[{{1, 3, 6}, {2, 3, 6}, {1, 5, 6}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], PlotMarkers -> markers]
```

[image]

Alternatively, using `PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"` and post-processing:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 3,6}, {2, 3, 6}, {1,5,6}}, PlotRangePadding->Scaled[.1],
 PlotMarkers ->{ "OpenMarkers", 25}] /.
      { p:_Disk|_Polygon:> {FaceForm[], p}, 
      AbsoluteThickness[_]:> AbsoluteThickness[2]}
```

[image]