# How do I make PlotLegends appear graphic symbols in the correct color?

Tags: plotting

If I create this plot

```
Data1 = Table[{X, X}, {X, 1, 10}];
Data2 = Table[{2 X, X}, {X, 1, 10}];
ListPlot[{Data1, Data2},
 PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics[Circle[]], 
    15}, {Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], FaceForm[], 
      Rectangle[]}], 13.96}},
 PlotLegends -> {"1,", "2"},
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Black}]
```

the circle in the legend appears black as I want it to. However the rectangle is gray. If I choose Green as the second argument of EdgeForm, both the symbols in the plot and the symbol in the legend shows as green. How do I make Mathematica show a proper black icon in the legend?[image]

Comment: You may be interested in the PolygonPlotMarkers package: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094/12

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I wish I would have known about this, before setting all of my markers manually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. The reason why the rectangle appears grey instead of black (even though you explicitly set `Black`) is that by default the legend generator adds an `EdgeForm` directive that lowers opacity. If you explicitly set the opacity as well, `EdgeForm[Opacity[1]]`, either in the definition of your marker or in the `PlotStyle`, it will work as you required.