# How to mark the (0,0) co-ordinate by a star sign instead of a dot?

Tags: plotting

```
ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2},{x,-4,4},{y,-4,4}, 
 Contours->{1,9,16},ContourShading->{Red,Green,Blue,None},Epilog->{Black,PointSize[0.01],Point[{0,0}]}, 
 ContourStyle->{Red,Green,Blue},FrameLabel->{"a","b"}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the library PolygonMarker (it need to be downloaded first), which is also useful for producing better quality figures (it fixes the data point positioning bug):
[How can we make publication-quality PlotMarkers without version 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84857/how-can-we-make-publication-quality-plotmarkers-without-version-10/85094#85094)

For example:

```
Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]

star = Tooltip[
   Graphics[{FaceForm[Black], 
     EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[0.003], JoinForm["Miter"]}], 
     PolygonMarker["FivePointedStar", 1]}, ImageSize -> 30, 
    PlotRange -> 1.5, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0], 
   "FivePointedStar"];

ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 Contours -> {1, 9, 16}, ContourShading -> {Red, Green, Blue, None}, 
 Epilog -> {Inset[star, {0, 0}]}, ContourStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}]
```

> [image]

The answer provided below by High Performance Mark works in first approximation, however Mathematica is known to place markers not exactly in the correct place (this has been the case for ages, and surprisingly it hasn't been fixed yet). That's why the PlotMarkers library linked above is recommended for creating markers.
This problem is evident when enlarging the star:

High Performance Mark approach:

> [image]

PolygonMarker approach:

> [image]

As you can see, in the first case the arrow is not in the circles, but is below the centre, while when using the PolygonMarker package this doesn't happen.

Comment: It's not working. It is showing an error like "PolygonMarker is not a Graphics primitive or directive."

Comment: have you installed the library?

Comment: in the link in my answer it is explained how to install the package

Comment: No, I haven't. I will try. However the another answer which is given above has been worked.

Comment: yes, the only problem with that approach is that the star is not exactly centered where it should be. this is a known problem in mathematica, that is fixed in the package I linked above

Comment: The problem is solved. Could you please edit or remove the plot(for copyright issues)? It would be highly appreciated if you do so. Please.

Comment: Hi @SahabubJahedi, I won't remove the plot from my answer. Posts on stackexchange help many readers and not only who posts the original answer, and removing the plots would make my answer incomplete, hence not useful for others. I'm sure you won't have any problem uploading your notes. You can slightly change the color scheme, the circle dimensions, the frame width and labels: no software (nor anyone with good sense) would check/complain about these plots on stackexchange. And honestly, even if you don't edit the image and just copy-paste it from here, no one will ever care..

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
Epilog->{Black,PointSize[0.01],Point[{0,0}]}
```

to

```
Epilog -> {Text["\[FivePointedStar]", {0, 0}]}
```

(*Mathematica* will take care of replacing `\[FivePointedStar]` with a five-pointed star).  For more control over the star's size and other characteristics you might want to experiment with styled text, perhaps

```
Epilog -> {Text[Style["\[FivePointedStar]", "Large"], {0, 0}]}
```

This latter epilog produces

[image]

*Mathematica* has a lot of symbols, shapes, icons, *etc* available in its collections of special characters, and can of course use Unicode too.

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much.

Comment: you might be interested into the PolygonMarker package, as mathematica places the symbols in the "wrong place" (it's an annoying known "bug" that has been known forever and never fixed). That package also uses the same collection of shapes but fixes the positioning. See answer above for more details

Comment: The problem is solved. Could you please edit or remove the plot(for copyright issues)? It would be highly appreciated if you do so. Please.

Comment: No, I won't.  If anyone owns the copyright in my creations it's me, and I hereby irrevocably donate it to the world to do with as it wishes.

Comment: Please try to understand. Actually, I am trying to make some notes. This plot may be there with the same legend name. So. If I try to upload in some specific online portal they may not allow me to upload it. I will be highly obliged if you edit it or remove it. Please, it's a request.

Comment: @SahabubJahedi as I said above, you can't ask people to remove their answers. If you think you are asking for something that you don't want to be in public domain, then you shouldn't ask in the first place. This is a q&a system where each post is potentially useful to many people, not only to who posts the question: removing answers that solve the original problem would defeat the very purpose of this site. And in any case, I'm quite positive that no one will care if in your notes there is an image similar to the ones we posted here.

Comment: @Fraccalo Thank you so much. I have understood how to tackle this. No, problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
star = Graphics@ WindingPolygon[CirclePoints[5][[{1, 3, 5, 2, 4}]]];

ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  Contours -> {1, 9, 16}, 
  ContourShading -> {Red, Green, Blue, None}, 
  Epilog -> Inset[star, {0, 0}, Center, 1], 
  ContourStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}]
```

[image]

Use `Epilog -> Inset[star,{0,0}, Center, Scaled[.05]]` to get:

[image]

Comment: TIL `WindingPolygon`!

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: The problem is solved. Could you please edit or remove the plot(for copyright issues)? It would be highly appreciated if you do so. Please.