# ListPlot marker color and style for several lists

Tags: plotting

I have two lists of 2D data I would like to plot on a plane. These lists are of the same length `n` and are position-correlated to each other.

I need these lists to have two different colors, but share the same symbol for elements at position `i` in both lists.

For example, in the following image, the points with the same label should share the same symbol.

[image]

I have been struggling with `ListPlot` without success.

**EDIT:**

Is it possible to have two plot legends? One for the color and another for the symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot the datasets separately and combine them with `Show`:

```
pts1 = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
pts2 = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];

pl = Show[
 ListPlot[
  List /@ pts1,
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 1],
  PlotMarkers -> plotMarkers
  ],
 ListPlot[
  List /@ pts2,
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 2],
  PlotMarkers -> plotMarkers
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Example]

I used letters for plot markers. You can set `PlotMarkers` to `Automatic` to get the default shape. Also have a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094/731) for other options.

For legends, you could do something like this:

```
legend1 = PointLegend[
  {ColorData[97, 1], ColorData[97, 2]},
  {"Data A", "Data B"}
  ]

legend2 = PointLegend[
  ConstantArray[ColorData[97, 1], 10],
  plotMarkers,
  LegendMarkers -> plotMarkers
  ]

Row[{
  Show[pl, ImageSize -> 400],
  legend1,
  legend2
  }]
```

[image: Multiple legends]

I'm using `Row` here, you might be needing a different approach to the layout depending on how you want to lay them out.

Comment: How could I have a legend for both color and markers with this solution?

Comment: @GuillermoOliver See my update.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: As an alternative, legends can be inserted and placed in the desired position, one per plot, using `PlotLegends`. No need to use `Row`, using `Show` to visualize both plots would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[99];
pts1 = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {15, 2}];
pts2 = First@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1, 2}] + # & /@ pts1;

pts1labeled = Transpose[{pts1, Alphabet[][[1 ;; Length@pts1]]}];
pts2labeled = Transpose[{pts2, Alphabet[][[1 ;; Length@pts2]]}];

ListPlot[{
  Callout[#1, #2, CalloutStyle -> Red] & @@@ pts1labeled
  , Callout[#1, #2, CalloutStyle -> Blue] & @@@ pts2labeled
  }
 , PlotLegends -> {
   Placed[
    SwatchLegend[
     Automatic, {"1", "2"}]
    , {After, Center}]
   , Placed[Panel[#, Alignment -> Center] &@LineLegend[
      ConstantArray[Black, Length@pts1]
      , Alphabet[][[1 ;; Length@pts1]]
      , LegendLayout -> {"Row", 2}
      ], Below
    ]
   }
 , PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}
 , PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}
 , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.15]
 , ImageSize -> 600
 , Epilog -> {
   Line /@ Transpose[{pts1, pts2}]
   }
 ]
```

---

[image]