# PDF export plot markers issue

Tags: export, pdf-format

I'm having an issue with a relatively textbook pdf export

```
ll2 = ListLinePlot[{Table[{i, 0.15 + 0.1 Sin[10 i]}, {i, 0., 0.15, 0.01}], Table[{i, 0.15 + 0.1 Cos[10 i]}, {i, 0., 0.15, 0.01}], Table[{i, 0.15 - 0.1 Sin[10 i]}, {i, 0., 0.15, 0.01}]}, PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "Monochrome"}]
Export["plot.pdf", ll2]
```

What I see on the screen is fine

[image: plot in mathematica]

But the exported pdf looks like this (never mind the black edges). Plot markers for the third curve are completely messed up.

[image: plot in exported pdf]

I have tried [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249973/bug-in-export-of-figures-with-plotmarkers) post, but to no avail. Same goes for any vector export format.