# How to mix two styles with some lines with filled and non-filled markers?

Tags: plotting, graphics, marker

How can I mix styles with some lines with filled and non-filled markers? 
 The post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84857/how-can-we-make-publication-quality-plotmarkers-without-version-10?noredirect=1&lq=1) mentioned all cases but I couldn't combine them into one plot.

```
(*Load the package code*)
package = 
  Import["http://raw.github.com/AlexeyPopkov/PolygonPlotMarkers/\
master/PolygonPlotMarkers.m", "Text"];

(*Install the package (existing file will be overwritten!)*)
Export[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", 
    "PolygonPlotMarkers.m"}], package, "Text"];
Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]
data = Table[{x, BesselJ[k, x]}, {k, 0, 4}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];
markers = {"Circle", "ThreePointedStar", "FourPointedStar", 
   "FivePointedStar", "Circle"};
colors = {Blue, Red, Darker@Green, Darker@Yellow, Orange};
Graphics[Table[{colors[[i]], Line[data[[i]]], FaceForm[White], 
   EdgeForm[{colors[[i]], AbsoluteThickness[1], JoinForm["Miter"]}], 
   PolygonMarker[markers[[i]], Offset[7], data[[i]]]}, {i, 
   Length[data]}], AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 450, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
(*Load the package code*)
package = 
  Import["http://raw.github.com/AlexeyPopkov/PolygonPlotMarkers/\
master/PolygonPlotMarkers.m", "Text"];

(*Install the package (existing file will be overwritten!)*)
Export[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", 
    "PolygonPlotMarkers.m"}], package, "Text"];
Needs["PolygonPlotMarkers`"]
data = Table[{x, BesselJ[k, x]}, {k, 0, 4}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];
markers = {"Circle", "ThreePointedStar", "FourPointedStar", 
   "FivePointedStar", "Circle"};
colors = {Blue, Red, Darker@Green, Darker@Yellow, Orange};
Graphics[Table[{colors[[i]], Line[data[[i]]], FaceForm[White], 
   EdgeForm[{colors[[i]], AbsoluteThickness[1], JoinForm["Miter"]}], 
   PolygonMarker[markers[[i]], Offset[7], 
    data[[i]], {Dynamic@EdgeForm[{CurrentValue["Color"], Opacity[1]}],
      Dynamic@FaceForm@Lighter[CurrentValue["Color"], 0.75]}]}, {i, 
   Length[data]}], AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 450, 
 Frame -> True]
```

Comment: What is the role of `Dynamic` in your attempted code? Also, what would you like to achieve? Which markers would you like to be filled, and which ones should be hollow?

Comment: @MarcoB I copied it from the linked page. I think it's to get the color to fill. Any lines are filled are okay as this is just an example.

Comment: It may be as simple as just removing the `FaceForm[White]` portion from the code you posted, and it might work. Note that `PolygonMarker` should really be `ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"]` if you are using the version of this code posted on the Wolfram Function Repository.