# Changing Point Style in Point

Tags: plotting

I was trying to show a point in ListContourPlot, for that I use Epilog ->[Point[]], as follow-

```
ListContourPlot[STParameterSpaceData, Contours -> {2.3, 6.18, 11.83}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.05, 0.05}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True,
  AspectRatio -> 0.8, Frame -> True, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 18], 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], ImageSize -> 400, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(S\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(T\)]\)"}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], {Green, Thick}, 
   Directive[Darker[Blue], Thick]}, 
 ContourShading -> {Red, Green, Darker[Blue], White}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.03], Yellow, Point[#] & /@ STBestFittedData}, 
 FrameTicks -> ticks, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

With that I am getting this plot:-
[image]

But I want to make the point to look like a *. But I can not find any command to change the point style from point to *. Can any one help me how I can do this?

Comment: A `Point[]` is a circular point. You can change the color and size.  You might try `Show[ListContourPlot[...], ListPlot[STBestFittedData, PlotMarkers -> Style["*", Large]]`.

Comment: You really should post a complete working example, so that we might test our ideas....

Comment: See also the documentation for `PlotMarkers` and this Q&A: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84857/how-can-we-make-publication-quality-plotmarkers-without-version-10 and its associated `ResourceFunction`, https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PolygonMarker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function instead of the Point:

```
star[x_, y_, r_] := 
  Graphics[{Red, 
    Line[Table[{{r*Cos[2 \[Pi] k/6] + x, r*Sin[2 \[Pi] k/6] + y}, {x,y}}, {k, 1, 6}]]}, ImageSize -> 8];
```

Play with this example to see, how to operate:

```
Manipulate[Show[{
   Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}],
   star[x, y, r]
   }], {{x, 0}, -1, 1}, {{y, 0}, -1, 1}, {{r, 0.02}, 0, 0.03}]
```

[image]

Have fun!